# LibGDX: How to move a rectangle with a finger?

Tags: android, events, libgdx, move, drag

I am trying implement moving a rectangle with my finger with libgdx but when I run the code on my phone it doesnt work, the rectangle stays in the upper left corner. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
ShapeRenderer shape;
public int xpos;
    public int ypos;
@Override
public void create () {
    shape = new ShapeRenderer();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 255, 255, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    shape.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    shape.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
    shape.rect(xpos, ypos, 100, 100);
    shape.end();  
} 
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    xpos = Gdx.input.getX();
    ypos = Gdx.input.getY();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    xpos = Gdx.input.getX();
    ypos = Gdx.input.getY();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    xpos = Gdx.input.getX();
    ypos = Gdx.input.getY();
    return true;
}
```

I have also implemented every other method of the `InputProcessor` interface and gave them a `return false` statement. But like I said it doesn't work...

Comment: Don't forget to call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);`.

Comment: Give us some more info. Are  methods you implemented from InputProcessor called at all?

Comment: I have already got it to work by deleting all the input processor stuft and by adding this if statement to the render Method: if(Gdx.isTouched(){xpos = Gdx.input.getX() and the same with the ypos and then you just add ypos = height - ypos or something like that I  don't have the code in mind but that worked for me but thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched() &&rectangle.contains(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight() -Gdx.input.getY())) {
     rectangle.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY(), 200, 100);
} 
else {
     rectangle.set(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, 200, 100); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please remove extra indentation from your code to make it more readable. Best regards